# SQL Case Expression with a Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, case

I have the following example Data set that was created by the following query that sets an employee as "Active' or 'Inactive" based on if they worked any hours during a month.

```
Select  Concat([First Name],' ', [Last Name]) AS 'FullName',
CASE (SUM([Week 1] + [Week 2] + [Week 3] + [Week 4]))
        When 0 Then 'Inactive'
        ELSE 'Active'
END [Status]
From dbo.hours
Group by [first name], [last name]
```

| FullName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Alan Brewer | Active |
| Alejandro McGuel | Inactive |
| Alex Nayberg | Active |

Im trying to get rid of all the 'Active' Status rows so that my query only displays those who are 'inactive'.  I attempted to add WHERE Status = Inactive between the FROM and GROUP BY expression but it returns no results.  (Does not give an error, just returns empty columns).

Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `WHERE` condition on the `Status` column just like that since it's not available to `WHERE` clause .. you can use that query as inline view and do the condition check in outer query like

```
select * from (
Select  Concat([First Name],' ', [Last Name]) AS 'FullName',
CASE (SUM([Week 1] + [Week 2] + [Week 3] + [Week 4]))
        When 0 Then 'Inactive'
        ELSE 'Active'
END [Status]
From dbo.hours
Group by [first name], [last name] ) xxx
where Status != 'Active';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `HAVING` clause, but also for your requirement you don't need the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  CONCAT([First Name],' ', [Last Name]) AS FullName,
        'Inactive' [Status]
FROM dbo.hours
GROUP BY [first name], [last name]
HAVING SUM([Week 1] + [Week 2] + [Week 3] + [Week 4]) = 0
```

Comment: @AnthonyColes fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

CTE will work as well:

```
with cte as(
Select  Concat([First Name],' ', [Last Name]) AS 'FullName',
CASE (SUM([Week 1] + [Week 2] + [Week 3] + [Week 4]))
        When 0 Then 'Inactive'
        ELSE 'Active'
END [Status]
From dbo.hours
Group by [first name], [last name])
select FullName from cte where Status <> 'Active'
```